# Swift3: How to save UITextView data in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitextview, swift3, uitableview

How do you save a `UITextView` data in a `UITableViewCell` respectively? I have two files, one is `TableViewController` and `descViewController`. In `TableViewController`, an array of words are stored and each cell is connected to `descViewController`, where a `UITextView` is set. I want to save the text data in each cell. How am I able to do it? The following is my attempt which almost succeeded

**- In my descViewController;**

```
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
var passedValue = ""
var passedText = ""
@IBOutlet weak var myTextView: UITextView!
```

**In viewDidLoad Inside descViewController**

```
myTextView.delegate = self
myTextView.text = passedText
myTextView.font = UIFont(name: "times new roman", size: 15)
myLabel.text = passedValue
```

**- In my TableViewController;**

```
  func textData() -> String {

    if let txt = textViewUserDefaults.object(forKey: "txtData") as? String {
       return txt
    }
    return ""
}

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Get Cell Label
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!;
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "desc") as! descViewController

    viewController.passedValue = (currentCell?.textLabel?.text)!
    viewController.passedText = textData()
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
    self.present(navController, animated: false , completion: nil)
}
```

I have created this method. The destination when each cell is clicked is `descViewController` where I prepared `passedText` and `passedValue`. This `passedValue` is a `UIlable`. This lable is for a `String` to be displayed in `descViewController` This result is successful. However, although my text view data is passed successfully, every cell data is going to hold the same value. For example, if I write something like "Today is a sunny day!", save it, and when I click another cell to open `descViewController`, the result is "Today is a sunny day!" in my text view. This is trouble I have right now. Code I wrote for storing data is in the following; `textViewUserDefaults` is a name I set by using `UserDefaults.Standard`.

```
textViewUserDefaults.set(self.myTextView.text, forKey: "txtData")
```

I want to have each cell hold each value. Could you provide me with code that works successfully?

Thank you

Comment: Use NSMutablearray for store value and get or pass value to next view controller

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya Could you provide me with the code? I am not familiar with writing the NSMUtableArray code. Thanks.

Comment: check my answer and whats is different between passedValue and passedText ?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya my writing was bad. I should have written passedLebel. So they are totally diffferent. So I only focus o n passed Text. IN the answer below, there is an error meesage saying you cannot use type NSMutableArray  to type of String

Comment: At which line you face this error ?

Comment: for textData() The UIlabel is fine at all. Only UITextVIew data. This is not being stored correctly

Comment: lets discussion on chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126292/discussion-between-himanshu-moradiya-and-ryohei).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 let YOURARRAYNAME : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
```

When user enter some text and submit it then add that text in your array

```
YOURARRAYNAME.addObject(YOURTEXT)
```

In this method

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
```

You got tableview cell index path so when you want to pass a data

```
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "desc") as! descViewController

viewController.passedValue = YOURARRAYNAME.objectAtIndex(indexpath.row) // here you pass text and what is passedvalue i dont know so you check this
viewController.passedText = textData() // what is your passedtext and textdata() you also pass value here 
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
self.present(navController, animated: false , completion: nil)
```

Comment: You can use swift array instead of oldschool NSMutableArray. it would be `var dataSource = [String]()`